# clickable menubarItem for top level node on new jqueryui menubar?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drop-down-menu, jquery-1.7, jquery-ui-menu

I'm investigating the [new jqueryui menubar](http://view.jqueryui.com/master/demos/menubar/default.html).

The menubar seems to work well, but sometimes you have a menu item that doesn't have children.  I modified the above default demo to have a top level clickable menu item. The mouseover shows the correct URL in the toolbar but it doesn't fire when clicked on.

```
<div class="menubarItem ui-menubar-item" role="presentation">
    <a href="#topLevelMenu" class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1" role="menuitem" id="toplevelmenu">
        <span class="ui-button-text">
            <!-- url should change to #topLevelMenu but doesn't -->
            Clickable Top Menu
        </span>
    </a>
</div>
```

I put my example into [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/epigaf/2/edit#source). This code doesn't show the hash changes running in JS Bin but does show them if you save the html locally.

Any thoughts on how to get the top menu clickable (vs. a dropdown)?

Comment: You have to edit [this code](http://view.jqueryui.com/master/ui/jquery.ui.menubar.js) so that `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` become `click`.